# Can we use PHP in Node red platform?

Tags: php, node-red

I am trying to make a dynamic web page in the Node-red platform to show realtime sensor value on the webpage. Is it possible to use PHP in Node-red? Any example?

Comment: Please include more info. What exactly are you trying to do? The more details you give us, the better we can answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

There is no PHP rendering nodes for Node-RED.

A quick look on npm only shows one PHP NodeJS node, that hasn't been touched in 7 years and is marked at not working so it is very unlikely that it could be wrapped as a Node-RED node.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you should look at the following:

- [node-red-dashboard](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-dashboard)
- [node-red-contrib-uibuilder](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-uibuilder)
- The core template node